# Set y axis limits R

Tags: r

I am trying to plot a histogram and I tried the following. First I tried this

> x<-hist(t$Sum_of_OHR.s,breaks=c(0,0.05,0.10,0.15,0.20,0.25,0.30,0.35,0.40,0.45,0.50,0.55,0.60,0.65,0.70,0.75,0.80,0.85,0.90,0.95,1.00))

but that did not set proper limits for the y axis i.e in spite of having a count more than 5000 the axis limit was displayed as 4000. This works

```
> histr<-hist(t$Sum_of_OHR.s,breaks=c(0,0.05,0.10,0.15,0.20,0.25,0.30,0.35,0.40,0.45,0.50,0.55,0.60,0.65,0.70,0.75,0.80,0.85,0.90,0.95,1.00),ylim=c(0,6000))
```

The problem however is that the count may change drastically depending on the data. So, I need something that would set the y limits based on the data. Could someone please tell me how I should go about it?

Comment: A quick comment; R doesn't label the "limits" on a plot, just a few locations on each axis that looks nice to us humans.  If you really want the limits labelled you'd probably want to force that in yourself, by calling `axis` explicitly

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can add a variable in place of the 6000 so you could sum or count your y variable and then add 10% or an amount you feel comfortable with as a means of padding it.

e.g.

```
ysize<-sum(t$Sum_of_OHR.s)*1.1
cbreaks<-seq(0,1,by=0.05)
histr<-hist(t$Sum_of_OHR.s,breaks=cbreaks,ylim=c(0,ysize))
```